# Basic Selenium grid 4.8.0 in two computers and Firefox

Tags: selenium-grid

I want to execute test in several computers or VM's but the execution gives me the SessionNotCreatedExeption, I'm thinking that's because of the node couldn't find the driver

according to documentation from selenium grid I just created my nodes with the following command

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.8.0.jar node --hub http://<hostIP>:4444
```

Currently I wanted to run test with Firefox

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;

public class ParallelTest {    
    private WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        if(driver == null) {
            String cloudUrl = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\SeleniumHub4\\geckodriver.exe");
            FirefoxOptions browserOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(cloudUrl), browserOptions);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        Date fecha = new Date();
        System.out.println(fecha + " Test 1 executed on: " + ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        Date fecha = new Date();
        System.out.println(fecha + " Test 2 executed on: " + ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName());
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
        driver = null;
    }
}
```

And this is the output of my console

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Could not start a new session. Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Timed out waiting for driver process to start.
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_361'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown 
Host info: host: 'hostName', ip: 'hostIP'
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_361'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.16'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {}}}]
Capabilities {}     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at ParallelTest.setUp(ParallelTest.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:361)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:296)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:823)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:590)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:969)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) 
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Could not start a new session. Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Timed out waiting for driver process to start.
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_361'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown 
Host info: host: 'hostName', ip: 'hostIP'
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_361'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.16'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {}}}]
Capabilities {}     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at ParallelTest.setUp(ParallelTest.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:361)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:296)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:823)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:590)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:969)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Feb 16, 2023 11:16:46 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.opentelemetry.OpenTelemetryTracer createTracer
INFO: Using OpenTelemetry for tracing Test ignored. Test ignored. ===============================================
Parallel test suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 2
Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 1
=============================================== 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: It would be beneficial if you also include the stacktrace when you run the program.

Answer (score 0):

The thing was that I was using the incorrect driver, the thing was that I was using version 0.32.2 but unfortunately for this version there is no geckodriver for win64 so I downloaded win-aarch64 driver

[image: Wrong driver]

So at the end only had to downgrade to the 0.32.1 version and that was my solution

[image: Correct driver]

Lesson be sure you're getting the right driver before posting here in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have removed the question from your answer. Please don't ask follow-up questions in answers. If you have a follow-up question, post a new question (assuming it is on-topic, which yours was not)